# JavaScript get devices in client’s wifi

Tags: javascript, html, client, wifi, webclient

I was wondering if you could use JavaScript on client side to scan the WiFi and list all the devices in it.
It seems to be possible as you can connect to devices in Spotify Web…

So is it possible and which approach would you take on it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package that searches all local devices connected to your network

https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-devices

Comment: It's using `arp` , so I can't use it on client side. Thanks anyway